# ember file upload to rails, encoding and decoding with base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload, ember.js, decode

I'm almost there, but I'm having an issue with decoding of the file. When decoding the file is not correct.

The code that I use to upload the file:

```
  createDataSet: function() {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('original_filename', this.get('fileName'));
    data.append('datafile', this.get('newData'));
    data.append('project_id', this.get('content.id'));
    data.append('name', this.get('content.name'));
    $.ajax({
      url: '/data_sets.json',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('ok');
      },
      error: function(xhr, data, errorThrown) {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
  }
```

On the Rails side I'm trying to pick this up with the following method:

```
  def create
    # take care of the attachement
    datasetfilename = Pathname.new(params[:original_filename]).basename
    newfile = File.open(datasetfilename, 'w') do |f|
      f.write(Base64.decode64(params[:datafile]))
    end

    @dataset = DataSet.new
    @active_data_set = @dataset.active_data_sets.build
    @active_data_set.project_id = params[:project_id]
    @active_data_set.save
    @dataset.name = params[:name]
    @dataset.filename = datasetfilename
    @dataset.tempfilename = @dataset.savefile newfile
    @dataset.save
  end
```

If I use `File.open(datasetfilename, 'w')` I get an error like this one `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError - "\xAB" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`. On the other hand, if I open with `'wb'` the resulting file is mingled and can't be read.

I already added the meta tag for the file encoding `<meta charset="utf-8" />` but without any difference.

If anybody has any hint that would be appreciated.

Comment: If you call FormData on a form DOM object it will encode the file for you from the input of type file: new FormData($('form'));  Otherwise you will need to encode the file before you add it to the FormData object.

Comment: At the moment with the setup above the parameters look like "datafile"=>"data:text/csv;base64,SUR4CUluZ... Which is why I assumed it was encoded already in base64.

Comment: I ended up using [jquery-fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which made it very simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just got this working in one of my own controllers, there are 2 main issues:

1)  to resolve the encoding issue, use "w:binary" as the write flag instead of "w" (defaults to ASCII)

2)  the :datafile params includes some header info "data:text/csv;base64,SUR4CUluZ...", I'm currently splitting on "," but might be better served to decode everything beyond "base64," as I'm not sure if additional commas are allowed.

My working code (slightly different parameter names):

```
if params.key?(:img_file)
  header, data = params[:img_file].split(',')
  img_type = header.match(/image\/([a-z]{1,11});/)[1]
  file_path = "imgtodo/fund_#{@fund.id}.#{img_type}"
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public',file_path).to_s, 'w:binary') do |f|
    f.write(Base64.decode64(data))
  end
end
```